# Tag merge request [build-order] -> [starcraft-2]

Tags: discussion, tag-merging

Please can [build-order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build-order) be merged into [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2), as all questions tagged with the former are tagged with the latter, and [build-order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build-order) is earmarked for burnination.

If merging is strongly opposed, renaming to [starcraft-2-build-order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2-build-order) is a suitable alternative.

Comment: The rename can't hurt. I'll let another mod decide about the fate of [tag:sc2-build-order].

Answer (score 2):

I would believe that the rename is preferred. I could see myself asking questions tagged with [build-order] for other games, such as League of Legends (what is a good starter build order for 'insert champion here').